# To get differnce in days and store in variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send difference of days along with other data to a POST Url.

Form has 2 date fields from which difference in days should be calculated upon 'Saving' the data.

```
<div className = "form-group">
  <label>Booking Day</label>
  <input type="date" id = "bookingDate" placeholder="Booking Date..." name="bookingDate" 
    className="form-control" value={this.state.bookingDate} onChange= 
    {this.changeBookingDateHandeler}/>
</div>
<br />
<div className = "form-group">
  <label>Check Out Date</label>
  <input type="date" id = "checkOutDate" placeholder="Check Out Date..." name="checkOutDate" 
    className="form-control" value={this.state.checkOutDate} onChange= 
    {this.changeCheckoutDateHandeler}/>
</div>
<br />
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick = {this.saveGuests}>Save</button>
```

Save Function

```
saveGuests = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //difference is days
    const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    function dateDifference(){
      const bookingDate = this.state.bookingDate;
      const checkOutDate = this.state.checkOutDate;
      const utc1 = Date.UTC(checkOutDate.getDay());
      const utc2 = Date.UTC(bookingDate.getDay());
      return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
    }
    const days = dateDifference();
    //payload
    let guest = {
      lastName : this.state.lastName,
      firstName : this.state.firstName,
      rooms : this.state.rooms,
      bookingDate: this.state.bookingDate,
      checkOutDate: this.state.checkOutDate,
      days: days,
    };
    console.log('guest =>' + JSON.stringify(guest));
    //sending post request
    HotelBookService.createGuests(guest).then(res => {
      this.props.history.push('/HotelBook');
    });
  }
```

However, it shows state error for these 2 consts `(bookingDate, checkOutDate)` declared inside `dateDifference()`

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

Here is the full file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import HotelBookService from '../services/HotelBookService';
class CreateGuests extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      lastName:'',
      firstName:'',
      rooms:'',
      bookingDate:'',
      checkOutDate:'',
      days: '',
    }
    this.cancel_add_guests = this.cancel_add_guests.bind(this);
    this.changeLastNameHandeler = this.changeLastNameHandeler.bind(this);
    this.changeFirstNameHandeler = this.changeFirstNameHandeler.bind(this);
    this.changeRoomsHandeler = this.changeRoomsHandeler.bind(this);
    this.changeBookingDateHandeler = this.changeBookingDateHandeler.bind(this);
    this.changeCheckoutDateHandeler = this.changeCheckoutDateHandeler.bind(this);
    this.saveGuests = this.saveGuests.bind(this);
  }
  cancel_add_guests(){
    this.props.history.push('/HotelBook');
  }
  changeLastNameHandeler = (event) => {
    this.setState({lastName : event.target.value});
  }
  changeFirstNameHandeler = (event) => {
    this.setState({firstName : event.target.value});
  }
  changeRoomsHandeler = (event) => {
    this.setState({rooms : event.target.value});
  }
  changeBookingDateHandeler = (event) => {
    this.setState({bookingDate : event.target.value});
  }
  changeCheckoutDateHandeler = (event) => {
    this.setState({checkOutDate : event.target.value});
  }
  saveGuests = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //difference is days
    const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    function dateDifference(){
      const bookingDate = this.state.bookingDate;
      const checkOutDate = this.state.checkOutDate;
      const utc1 = Date.UTC(checkOutDate.getDay());
      const utc2 = Date.UTC(bookingDate.getDay());
      return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
    }
    const days = dateDifference();
    //payload
    let guest = {
      lastName : this.state.lastName,
      firstName : this.state.firstName,
      rooms : this.state.rooms,
      bookingDate: this.state.bookingDate,
      checkOutDate: this.state.checkOutDate,
      days: days,
    };
    console.log('guest =>' + JSON.stringify(guest));
    //sending post request
    HotelBookService.createGuests(guest).then(res => {
      this.props.history.push('/HotelBook');
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <div className = "container-fluid"><button type="buton" className="btn btn-primary" onClick = {this.cancel_add_guests}>Back</button></div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset">
                <h3 className="text-center">Add Guests</h3>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <form>
                    <div className = "form-group">
                      <label>Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Surname..." name="lastName" className="form-control" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.changeLastNameHandeler}/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className = "form-group">
                      <label>First Name</label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." name="firstName" className="form-control" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.changeFirstNameHandeler}/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className = "form-group">
                      <label>Rooms</label>
                      <input type="number" placeholder="Rooms..." name="rooms" className="form-control" value={this.state.rooms} onChange={this.changeRoomsHandeler}/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className = "form-group">
                      <label>Booking Day</label>
                      <input type="date" id = "bookingDate" placeholder="Booking Date..." name="bookingDate" className="form-control" value={this.state.bookingDate} onChange={this.changeBookingDateHandeler}/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className = "form-group">
                      <label>Check Out Date</label>
                      <input type="date" id = "checkOutDate" placeholder="Check Out Date..." name="checkOutDate" className="form-control" value={this.state.checkOutDate} onChange={this.changeCheckoutDateHandeler}/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick = {this.saveGuests}>Save</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick = {this.cancel_add_guests}>Cancel</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CreateGuests;
```

All, apart from `days` field in payload other fields, are working fine.

Please suggest, how I'll be able to calculate the day differnce and send it alike others to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this keyword inside a normal function which has no leading parent object.

```
 function dateDifference(){
      const bookingDate = this.state.bookingDate;
      const checkOutDate = this.state.checkOutDate;
      const utc1 = Date.UTC(checkOutDate.getDay());
      const utc2 = Date.UTC(bookingDate.getDay());
      return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
    }
    const days = dateDifference();
```

Here calling dateDifference withotu any leading object will lead to undefined when we access using this keyword inside the function.

you can either bind the function call by

```
   const days = dateDifference.bind(this);
```

or you can use arrow function as it will check for lexical scope.

```
 const dateDifference=()=>{
          const bookingDate = this.state.bookingDate;
          const checkOutDate = this.state.checkOutDate;
          const utc1 = Date.UTC(checkOutDate.getDay());
          const utc2 = Date.UTC(bookingDate.getDay());
          return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
        }
        const days = dateDifference();
```